# how to filter year and month in database column added date and also how check that year and month data possible in database

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, date

If I select a year and month (as in the image below) how can I check that data exists in database? Also, how can I filter date to year and month.

[image]

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <strong>Posting Period</strong>
    </td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Year</td>
    <td>
        <input type="number" value="2015"id="year" name="txt_start_date"/>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Period</td>
    <td>
        <select style="width:150px;" id="month" name=month value=''onchange="run();">
            Select Month</option>
            <option value='01'>January</option>
            <option value='02'>February</option>
            <option value='03'>March</option>
            <option value='04'>April</option>
            <option value='05'>May</option>
            <option value='06'>June</option>
            <option value='07'>July</option>
            <option value='08'>August</option>
            <option value='09'>September</option>
            <option value='10'>October</option>
            <option value='11'>November</option>
            <option value='12'>December</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
```

Actually when I select those two fields, how can I check?

Comment: Can you include what you have tried in your PHP controller, and model?

Answer (score 0):

You will using below query to fetch data on base of year and month

```
SELECT * 
FROM   catalog_product_entity 
WHERE  ( YEAR('field_name_in_db_table')  = 'year' 
AND      MONTH('field_name_in_db_table') = 'month')
```

here year is `2014`, `2015` etc., and month is any number between `01` to `12`

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how to create a sql query for this using codeigniter then try the following in your model:

```
function getTableInfo($year, $month) {
    $this->db->select();
    $this->db->from("mytable");
    $this->db->where("mytable.year", $year);
    $this->db->where("mytable.month", $month);
    $q = $this->db->get();
    return $q->result();
}
```